# Facebook Login Error PassportJS

Tags: facebook, express, passport.js

Im using PassportJS for Facebook login in ExpressJS app. I received a recent error which didn't encountered before.

```
Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: An error occurred while 
processing this request. Please try again later.

{
error: {
    name: 'InternalOAuthError',
    message: 'failedtofetchuserprofile',
    oauthError: {
        statusCode: 500,
        data: '{
            "error": {
                "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
                "type": "OAuthException",
                "code": 2
            }
        }'
    }
}
```

}

I don't have idea why I got the error. App ID and Key wasn't changed and sandbox was disabled.

Comment: If this started happening within the last few hours, it's probably related to the Facebook downtime they are experiencing right now.

Comment: I have this error only with certain users (seems like users not often using facebook)